# Remove dynamically loaded tooltips table tr if text is NA

Tags: javascript, jquery

Remove dynamically loaded tooltips table tr

I have charts so each charts bar have tooltips its shows to value previous bar value and current hover bar value so i want to hide the tr if the text NA in td. i have done below code but its not working

```
<div class="customTooltipRapsure">
<div class="scrollingTooltip">
<table id="tooltipTable">
<tbody>
<tr class="OldGrossBudget">
<td>Old Gross Budget </td>
<td>NA</td>
</tr>
<tr class="NewGrossBudget">
<td>New Gross Budget </td>
<td class="text-right">9,964.72</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".customTooltipRapsure #tooltipTable tbody tr td").filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() === "NA";
    }).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove NA td using javascript

```js
function removeTR(){
 var tableToolTip = document.getElementById('tooltipTable');
    const table = document.getElementById('tooltipTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (let x = 0; x < table.length; x++) {
      const row = table[x];
            const tds= row.getElementsByTagName("td");
      for (let y = 0; y < tds.length; y++) {
        if (tds[y].innerText == "NA") {
                    table[x].remove();
          break;
        }
      }
    }
}

removeTR();
```

```html
<div class="customTooltipRapsure">
<div class="scrollingTooltip">
<table id="tooltipTable">
<tbody>
<tr class="OldGrossBudget">
<td>Old Gross Budget </td>
<td>NA</td>
</tr>
<tr class="NewGrossBudget">
<td>New Gross Budget </td>
<td class="text-right">9,964.72</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure using filter to find column with text "NA" , so i use another method

```js
const table = $("#tooltipTable tbody tr")
for (let x = 0; x < table.length; x++) {
  const row = $("#tooltipTable tbody").find(`tr:eq(${x})`)

  for (let y = 0; y < row.find("td").length; y++) {
    if (row.find(`td:eq(${y})`).text() == "NA") {
      row.find(`td:eq(${y})`).closest("tr").remove();

    }
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border: solid 2px black;
}

td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="customTooltipRapsure">
  <div class="scrollingTooltip">
    <table id="tooltipTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="OldGrossBudget">
          <td>Old Gross Budget </td>
          <td>NA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="NewGrossBudget">
          <td>New Gross Budget </td>
          <td class="text-right">9,964.72</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

first you need to loop total row , then loop total column finally find column with text "NA"
hope this will solve your problem

Comment: thanks for answer after adding your code still NA tr shows because its show one charts bar mouse over so those value keep aaded dynamically